# MySQL data integrity check. How to decode or un-hash a MySQL Password on Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encryption, cryptography

I am running an integrity check on a MySQL database backup that is used on Laravel version 5.7. And I would like to know how to decode the password on the SQL. So far I have tried to decode the MySQL ecrypted password via: `Crypt::decrypt($db_password)` but  it returns **'The payload is invalid.'**

Thank you in advance

Current password on file: `1234567890`

Stored password on MySQL DB: `$2y$10$d7JXQPzt.UQreuS4o55wa.FdXWJpktzBpsQPRZxZIfhPoYiRgyS/a`

Provided App Key: `APP_KEY=base64:RP6YXIzzKtte7I6X8MlQMXTivA289+vA2wrr2yYbhwo=`

So far I have installed tinker: `$ php artisan tinker`

```
$db_password = '$2y$10$d7JXQPzt.UQreuS4o55wa.FdXWJpktzBpsQPRZxZIfhPoYiRgyS/a'
$encripted_value = Crypt::encrypt(1234567890)
$decripted_password = Crypt::decrypt($db_password)
```

**SQL DB**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `username`, `profile_pic`, `gender`, `role`, `zipcode`, `address`, `country_code`, `country_name`, `phone`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `dob`, `general_info`, `about_me`, `food_drink`, `entertainment`, `fitness_and_hobbies`, `travel_and_places`, `animal_lover`, `show_username`, `show_about_me`, `show_food_drink`, `show_entertainment`, `show_fitness_and_hobbies`, `show_travel_and_places`, `show_animal_lover`, `show_professions`, `remember_token`, `_token`, `lat`, `lng`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `firebase_id`) VALUES
(130, 'Admin', 'admin@admin.com', 'Admin', 'b45755c5969e2b039272e1f57b551f64.png', 1, 0, 'Mandi, Himachal Pradesh', 'Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh', NULL, NULL, '+91-8874786555', NULL, '$2y$10$d7JXQPzt.UQreuS4o55wa.FdXWJpktzBpsQPRZxZIfhPoYiRgyS/a', '1998-01-26', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, '1hBcdGau72pP2azRPvQvZCmdUsoa3z3XkvLKNGFW5qeLeouRxJSORaTfxiJV', '$2y$10$VEWopeHpOasq8xWfnezF8eJ331MP6iUepvJAKTSdAVaJ1/BRAQMrK297496', '', '', '2019-07-26 20:55:50', '2019-09-25 18:34:28', '0'),
```

Comment: You cannot decrypt a MySQL password. It is hashed for security

Comment: Hash is different from encryption. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms#:~:text=Whereas%20encryption%20is%20a%20two,are%20MD5%20and%20SHA%2D1%20.&text=Use%20hashes%20when%20you%20only%20need%20to%20go%20one%20way.

Comment: @ipegasus yes it's possible, see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing

Comment: Hi @EliasSoares Thank you. Via -> Hash::check('1234567890', $db_password) looks useful. Please feel free to post your answer and I can accept it.